# Java threads - variables local to the thread

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am struggling to understand on java threads work so excuse this rather simple question.

Let's assume I have a program with N threads.  Each thread executes the same instructions on a different part of an  array of Strings.   We invoke the thread through a class with a runnable interface.   For the purposes of this example, let say it is something like this:

```
run() {
    while (startStop = loopGetRange() != null) {

        countLetters(startStop.start,startStop.stop);
        /* start is the beginning cell in the array where the process starts
          and stop is the ending cell in the array where the process stops */
    }
}
```

Finally countLetters is just a simple method as follow:

```
private void countLeters (int start, int stop) {
    for (int y = start; <= stop; y++) {
        String theWord = globalArray[y];
        int z = theWord.length;
        System.out.println("For word "+theWord+" there are "+z+" characters");
    }
}
```

Here is my question:    Are variables like "theWord" and "Z"  local to the thread or are they shared across the thread and are thus subject to possible thread collisions.   If the latter, how best to protect these variables.

Thanks for helping a confused person.

Elliott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local variables are allocated on the stack, and are local to the thread. Only member fields are shared across threads. So, `theWord` and `Z` are not shared across threads and you don't need to worry about clashing.

Given that a String is immutable, the only concern about thread safety we would have in method countLeters() is access to the globalArray.

Now, if the construction of this array "happened-before" the access to globalArray, the code is safe as long as no thread "writes" to the globalArray.

"happened-before" relationships can be enforced by number of ways (by using the `synchronized` keyword, `final` keyword, `volatile` keyword, using `java.util.concurrent` libraries etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The thread has no impact on what variables are visible.  It would be just like you created the class and ran the method without starting a thread.  If multiple threads will be accessing the same objects, then you have to look at using locks to make sure they don't step on each other.

Comment: Thread local variables can be tracked for each thread, if you had a pool of threads to do work.  static variables will be shared across all instances of this runnable.

Comment: Yes, there is ThreadLocal but that doesn't look like what he was asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Like JOTN says, if the threads are accessing the same objects, then there might be thread collisions.

If the `globalArray` variable in this case is shared across the threads, and *especially* if it or its elements are *modified*, then it might be wise to use locks/synchronization.

Comment: OK.   The global array is not being modified.   I'm more concerned about the variables in the countLetters method. The, method called within the run.    If I'm understanding correctly, it would seem that variables local to the countLetters method could be subject to conclusions.    Is this correct?    If so, what of instead of calling countLetters as a method, I created a class called Count letters which invoked the wrapped method as part of its intantiation, would that get around the problem?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you mean by "subject to conclusions". But variables that are created within a method are local to the method. However, in the example you wrote, you do `String theWord = globalArray[y];`, where theWord becomes a reference to the object at `gloablArray[y]`. I'm not sure wrapping this in a class would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from visibility of variables and lock/synchronization issues for shared variables...

> Are variables like "theWord" and "Z" local to the thread

Those variables you ask about are local to the loop, not part of the class or instance, and exist on a per-thread basis, so there won't be any collisions.